# Priority Data Structures and Finding a winning program using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, priority-queue, ranking

I have a List of programTypes:

```
List<String> programTypes = {ACF, VCX, IFL}
Note: This is a map hardcoded in code.

Here, I want to attach priorities to these programTypes: 
ACF->priority=2, VCX->priority=1, IFL->priority=3
```

What data structure should I use? Priority Queues?

Also, now I have a list of inputProgramTypes: {ABC, VCX, IFL}
I want the output to be the winningProgramType: VCX

I can code it by iterating on **inputProgramTypes** and setting the winningProgramType if each next has a priority greater that the set one (Like finding max problem).

But I want to know if I can optimise? And how I can use streams to write code for same to make it look clean? I am new to streams and learning my way through it.

Comment: Can priorities of the programTypes/inputProgramTypes change or are they constant?

Comment: No they are hardcoded. They dont change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, a simple Map will do fine:

```
    public Map<String, Integer> buildMapOfPriorityProgramTypes() {
        Map<String, Integer> priorityProgramTypes = new HashMap<>();
        priorityProgramTypes.put("ACF", 2);
        priorityProgramTypes.put("VCX", 1);
        priorityProgramTypes.put("IFL", 3);
        return priorityProgramTypes;
    }

    public String getTopPriorityType(Map<String, Integer> priorityTypes) {

        return priorityTypes.entrySet().stream()
                .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .get().getKey();

    }
```

If you use Java 9 or newer, you may use shorter `Map.of`:

```java
Map<String, Integer> priorityProgramTypes = Map.of(
  "ACF", Integer.valueOf(2),
  "VCX", Integer.valueOf(1),
  "IFL", Integer.valueOf(3)
);
```

Comment: How will be my programType map stored in this case? Map<String, Int> programTypes = {(ACF, 3), (VCX, 1), (IFL, 2)} ?

Comment: Thanks. Want to know if I want to map another string to each programType along with the priority, how will this look like? Eg: (VCX,1, VProgram), (ACF, 2, AProgram) -> I want to store this kind of data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270011/finding-wining-program-using-enums-and-java-8 - I have posted another question for this as the structure of my data is different and to avoid confusion in this question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an enum with a parameter constructor.

Such, the method `public static Map<ProgramType, Integer> getPrioMap()` will elegantly and in a type-safe way return the data structure you need.

```
public enum ProgramType {

    ACF(2), VCX(1), IFL(3);

    private int prio;

    private ProgramType(int prio) {
        this.prio = prio;
    }

    public Integer getPriority() {
        return prio;
    }

    public static Map<ProgramType, Integer> getPrioMap() {
        return List.of(ProgramType.values()).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> e.getPriority()));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270011/finding-wining-program-using-enums-and-java-8 - I have posted another question for this as the structure of my data is different and to avoid confusion in this question

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface and its implementation [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

```
SortedMap<Integer, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(2, Collections.singletonList("ACF"));
map.put(1, Collections.singletonList("VCX"));
map.put(3, Collections.singletonList("IFL"));
```

The advantages are:

- The keys are sorted, you can manage the order of them defining a `Comparator` in the constructor [`new TreeMap<>(comparator);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-). The order of processing from the sample above will be:

  ```
  map.values().forEach(System.out::print);
  // [VCX][ACF][IFL]
  ```
- If more of the strings have the same priority, `List<String>` as the values of the map are more suitable.
- Adding new priority (key) and value (`List<String>`) to the map will not break the sorted characteristics. For safe adding, I recommend [`Map::computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-) .

Comment: Thanks. Want to know if I want to map another string to each programType along with the priority, how will this look like? Eg: (VCX,1, VProgram), (ACF, 2, AProgram) -> I want to store this kind of data

Comment: Yes, exactly, it will look like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270011/finding-wining-program-using-enums-and-java-8 - I have posted another question for this as the structure of my data is different and to avoid confusion in this question

Comment: You have done well :) However, mark as accepted one (and eventually upvote one or more) of the answers provided to leave this question answered and issue resolved. Other members might keep thinking of improving/posting answers.