# Finding wining program using enums and Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, enums, rank

I want to store data like:

```
(VCX, 1, VProgram), (ACF, 2, AProgram), (IFL, 3, IProgram) - //[ProgramType, priority, programName]

Input: inputProgramTypes: {ABC, VCX, IFL}

Output: winning programName based on priority // In this case: VProgram
```

So I am plannig to use a Enum with multiple values:

```
public enum ProgramType {
VCX("VProgram", 1),
ACF("AProgram", 2),
IFL("IProgram", 3);

ProgramType(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

ProgramType(final String name, final int prio) {
    this.name = name;
    this.prio = prio;
}
```

Is there any better way to store?

Also, I am not sure on the implemention of the method to getTopPrio using streams. (I can implement)

```
method: getTopPriority(List<> programTypeList) {
    impl using streams??
}
```

Comment: This depends on how often the program type data changes. Using an enum makes them effectively static (i.e. a change requires to recompile the program). For a more dynamic approach you should consider an array that is initialized for example from a configuration file.

Comment: Just verify this, is your query - "Give me the most prioritized program name."? Does your data represent it easily?

Comment: I find `TreeMap<Integer, List<ProgramType>>` data structure where the key is the priority and the value is a collection of the programs sufficient. The `ProgramType` would have `name` and `code` (and eventually `priority` that can be also the key of the map).

Comment: Would your priorities happen to be literally the ordinal number of their definition within the enum, the first being priority 1, the second being priority 2, and so on? If so, you do not need that priority field. Adding one to the result of the misnamed method `Enum::ordinal` will return that same number.

Answer (score 0):

`getTopPriority` can be implemented like this:

```
 ProgramType getTopPriority(List<ProgramType> programTypeList) {
    return programTypeList
            .stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparing(ProgramType::getPrio)).orElse(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
EnumSet
.copyOf( List.of( Month.JUNE , Month.FEBRUARY ) )
.iterator()
.next()
.toString()
```

> FEBRUARY

## Details

If your priority number happens to coincide with the ordinal number of each enum object’s place within the enum definition, your problem becomes simpler. That is, if the first enum object’s priority is 1, and the second is 2, and the third is 3, and so on.

Example `List` of enum objects.

```
List < Month > months = List.of( Month.JUNE , Month.FEBRUARY );
```

`EnumSet` is an implementation of `Set` optimized for handling enum objects. An `EnumSet` takes little memory and executes very quickly.

```
Set < Month > set = EnumSet.copyOf( months );
```

The iterator order of an `EnumSet` happens to be the order in which the enum objects are defined on that enum. So in our example of June & February, February comes first in the set. We simply ask for the first object from its iterator to solve your Question.

```
Month month = set.iterator().next();
```

> month.toString(): FEBRUARY

So you do not actually need to have that `prio` member field on your enum. You can get the ordinal number of each enum object by adding one to the `int` returned by the misnamed method `Enum::ordinal`.

```
Month.DECEMBER.ordinal() + 1
```

> 12

Omit the `prio` argument from your enum constructor. Add a method `getPriority`.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public enum ProgramType
{
    VCX( "VProgram" ), ACF( "AProgram" ), IFL( "IProgram" );

    private String displayName;

    ProgramType ( final String name )
    {
        this.displayName = name;
    }

    public String getDisplayName ( )
    {
        return this.displayName;
    }

    public int getPriorityLevel ( )
    {
        int priority = this.ordinal() + 1;  // `Enum::ordinal` method is misnamed, actually returning a zero-based index number rather than one-based ordinal number.
        return priority;
    }

    static ProgramType highestPriority ( List < ProgramType > programTypes )
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull( programTypes , "Received null list of program types. Message # 539b0b72-d28c-4e54-b82e-2e3b4d760f28." );
        if ( programTypes.isEmpty() ) { throw new IllegalArgumentException( "No program types specified (empty list). Message # 485b0856-a384-4090-aa5f-0d412cb0c8f6." );}

        ProgramType pt = 
                EnumSet
                .copyOf( programTypes )
                .iterator()
                .next()
        ;

        return pt ;  // Or return pt.getPriorityLevel() if the number was your intention.
    }
}
```

Example usage.

```
List < ProgramType > programTypes = List.of( ProgramType.IFL , ProgramType.ACF );
ProgramType pt = ProgramType.highestPriority( programTypes );
```

> pt.toString() = ACF
>
> pt.getPriorityLevel() = 2
>
> pt.getDisplayName() = AProgram